# Android View zoom in, zoom translating simultaneously

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-animation

I'm trying to make an android animation in which a view translates from left to right and it zoom in and zoom out sequentially during translation and whole animation is repeated infinite times. Following is my animation xml file but its output is unexpected. Kindly help me to achieve the desired solution.
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="10000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:repeatCount="-1"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />
    <set android:ordering="sequentially">
        <scale
            android:duration="500"
            android:fromXScale="0%"
            android:fromYScale="0%"
            android:repeatCount="-1"
            android:repeatMode="restart"
            android:toXScale="150%"
            android:toYScale="150%" />
        <scale
            android:duration="500"
            android:fromXScale="150%"
            android:fromYScale="150%"
            android:repeatCount="-1"
            android:repeatMode="restart"
            android:toXScale="0%"
            android:toYScale="0%"/>
    </set>
</set>
```

`